# Neo4j: Cypher for filtering based on list of properties

Tags: filter, neo4j, cypher

I have to write a cypher query that can filter a node based on its properties that comes from a list shown in code below.

```
UNWIND [{a_id:'1001', c_id:'1001'}] as row
match (a:Assembly)-[:RECIPE]->(c:Component)
where a.id = row.a_id and c.id = row.c_id and c.name = c_name and c.manu = c_manu
return c
```

My problem is that this codes assumes that in the list I will have all the properties sent to me and will return empty if all properties arent in the list. However the user can filter for one or any combination of the properties from the components (except for a_id 'This will always be in the list'). I dont know how to query, to ignore those that are not in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
UNWIND [{a_id:'1001', c_id:'1001'}] as row
MATCH (a:Assembly)-[:RECIPE]->(c:Component)
WHERE
  (NOT EXISTS(row.a_id) OR row.a_id = a.id) AND
  (NOT EXISTS(row.c_id) OR row.c_id = a.id) AND
  (NOT EXISTS(row.c_name) OR row.c_name = c.name) AND
  (NOT EXISTS(row.c_manu) OR row.c_manu = c.manu)
RETURN c
```